# AbstractScheduledService cancel runOneIteration

Tags: java, guava

I use the `AbstractScheduledService` to run tasks for a specific period. The tasks are checks, to see if a specific state is reached. If the desired state is reached I want to abort the `runOneIteration()` and shutdown the Executor.

Is it the right library for my use case? If not, what library should I use and if yes, how can I solve this problem. Calling `stopAsync` inside the `runOneIteration()` will lead to an `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException`. I searched a lot, but didn't find a helpful answer, to just cancel the scheduled service, if a specific state is reached.

```
@Override
protected void startUp ()
{
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, () -> "Start-Up of service");
}

@Override
protected void shutDown ()
{
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, () -> "Shut-Down of service");
}

@Override
protected void runOneIteration ()
{
    boolean result = this.checkIfServerIsOnline();
    if (result)
        // abort runOneIteration and shutdown scheduler
    else
        // continue check
}

@Override
protected Scheduler scheduler ()
{
    return AbstractScheduledService.Scheduler.newFixedRateSchedule(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```